# Why there are multiple folders for executable files in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, executable

I'm trying to understand Linux file system, and one of the question is:

1- Why there are multiple folders for executable files: `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin/` and `/usr/local/bin`? Is there any differences between them ?

2- If I have an executable file and I want to add it to my system, which of the third latter locations is the best for me ?

Comment: [Is the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard a UNIX standard or a GNU/Linux standard?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98751/is-the-filesystem-hierarchy-standard-a-unix-standard-or-a-gnu-linux-standard/)

Comment: Search this site for FHS, you'll find a lot of info is already here + the Wikipedia article. Mull that over and see they cover your Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run `man hier` from the command line to get the answer to your first question.
2. It depends. See [/usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux)

Comment: Hehe, "`man hier`" reads in German somewhat like "`man, [look] here!`" Which sounds like an unfriendly call or hint to look at something obvious. :)

Comment: Heh, yes. `hier` stands for "hierarchy" in this case.

Answer (score 6):

It's called the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and the gory details can be found [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

Generally:-

`/usr/bin` is for user programs.

`/usr/sbin` is for system programs - those that are used by admins, but not general users.

Both the above begin with `/usr` and the standard states that these could be hosted on a shared server (using NFS, for example) and accessed by the various hosts on a network.  The variants without the `/usr` (that is `/bin` and `/sbin`) are for essential programs that the system needs to boot (as the files in `/usr` tree won't be available if they're on a NFS share).

`/local/bin` are for locally compiled user programs.

If you have an executable, which wasn't installed using the system's package manager, then I suppose you should place it in `/usr/local/bin` if it's to be used by many users, or you could leave it in your home directory if it's only going to be used by yourself.